# Finding the average of values that are part of a delimited string

Tags: excel-formula, average, delimited

I have an Excel file that contains hundreds of rows and columns of delimited data. Every cell looks like these two sample cells, and it used alphas and symbols to represent a specific result:

```
2-0*0*8-15-8-T4-<2-D4-C4-$4-6-4->2-X4-^6-%-|0|-/P4
```

```
4-0*0*3-13-5-K3-<2-S3-C3-$3-11-7-999-M3-^1-+-|4|-/W3
```

Each piece of the data within the delimited structure refers to a testing result and each test is contained on a single row, ranging from about 50 to 600 cells.

My challenge is I need to come up with a way to get an average of the numeric values contained in the 16th delimited segment, the number contained within the pipes, for example "|0|" and "|4|" in the two examples above.

I have been using formulas such as this to count all the cells in a row that have both "S" and "/W" in the cell:

```
=COUNTIF('Test Data'!2:2,"*S*/W*")
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the average of the numbers contained within the pipes "|4|" etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the TEXTSPLIT() function?  It was just released this year and not all subscribers get it right away.  It makes solving this a lot simpler if you do.  So in your case getting just the number inside the pipes would start with something like INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,”|”),,2).    That says split the text into 3 columns delimited by the pipe symbol, and then the index provides only the second column.  In some cases you may have to place that in a VALUE function.  Let me know if you have access to TEXTSPLIT by trying it.

Comment: Max thanks, I have the ability to use TEXTSPLIT but in the production environment it's Excel Version Whatever, so I won't introduce version-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Max pointed out, TEXTSPLIT seems to be the best solution to your problem.

If you have to avoid TEXTSPLIT, here is an alternative:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(data,SEARCH("|",data,1)+1,SEARCH("|",data,SEARCH("|",data,1)+1)-SEARCH("|",data,1)-1)),""))
```

which can be slightly shortened to

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(LET(a,SEARCH("|",data,1),MID(data,a+1,SEARCH("|",data,a+1)-a-1))),""))
```

where 'data' is the array of rows and columns containing the test codes.